# How to create a panda Dataframe from a file that has Multiple rows of Lists?

Tags: python, list, dataframe, csv, for-loop

I have a file called customer.CR that contains multiple rows of lists. It looks like this:

```
1361886|5303477|CR|WY|WY & NW RAILROAD CO|UNKNOWN||UNKNOWN|WY|00000|C|100.000000000|29|HOLDER|
1280535|5394419|CR|WY|CHAMBERS JERRY|7800 E UNION AVE # 1100||DENVER|CO|802372715|P|100.000000000|15|LESSEE|
1324915|5312567|CR|WY|EXXONMOBIL OIL CORP|PO BOX 650232||DALLAS|TX|752650232|C|100.000000000|15|LESSEE|
...
```

I want to convert this file into a panda dataframe that looks like this but with many rows and 14 columns (here you can see 2 columns, but I need 14:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 1361886 | 5303477 |
| 1280535 | 5394419 |

I ran the following command:

```
myfile = dbdir + '/Data/customer.CR.load'
```

```
with open(myfile, newline = '') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='|')
    for row in csvreader:
        print(row)
```

I got the following result.

```
['1361886', '5303477', 'CR', 'WY', 'WY & NW RAILROAD CO', 'UNKNOWN', '', 'UNKNOWN', 'WY', '00000', 'C', '100.000000000', '29', 'HOLDER', '']
['1280535', '5394419', 'CR', 'WY', 'CHAMBERS JERRY', '7800 E UNION AVE # 1100', '', 'DENVER', 'CO', '802372715', 'P', '100.000000000', '15', 'LESSEE', '']
...
...
...

['1324915', '5312567', 'CR', 'WY', 'EXXONMOBIL OIL CORP', 'PO BOX 650232', '', 'DALLAS', 'TX', '752650232', 'C', '100.000000000', '15', 'LESSEE', '']
['1353999', '5325242', 'CR', 'WY', 'ULTRA RESOURCES INC', '1550 WYNKOOP ST STE 300', '', 'DENVER', 'CO', '802021648', 'C', '20.000000000', '15', 'LESSEE', '']
```

now I want to convert row to panda dataframe. I wrote the following command:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([row], index=None)
df
```

but in the output, I get just one row. My question is, how should I change my code so that I get a dataframe that has all the rows and columns? (Columns are separated by verticle pipe '|' in the file.

```
0   1       2       3   4   5       6     7 8   9   10    11          12                   13                       14
> 0 1306746 5466867 CR  WY  HUBER EMERICK M 311 S CONWELL ST        CASPER  WY  826012938   P   7.598157000 15  LESSEE
```

Comment: 1. Please, put whole code at once 2. Seems like you pass only one row after iteration to dataframe

Comment: Perhaps you could skip csv completely and just do `df = pd.read_csv(myfile, delimiter="|")`?